# SQL Server How to test if test all items in a table exist within another table within the context of a WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am processing postcode sectors using a stored procedure.

I am using a `WHILE` loop to iterate over the required processing.
On each iteration of the loop I need to test the current results table with a fixed table of results.

```
FixedResults
------------
Sector
BR1 1
BR1 2
BR1 3
BR1 4
BR1 5
BR1 9
```

First iteration of `TestResults` may return results:

```
TestResults
---------
Sector
BR1 1
BR1 2
BR1 3
```

Not all the results in `FixedResults` are in `TestResults` on this iteration, so the loop needs to continue.

The next loop iteration returns `TestResults` as:

```
TestResults
-----------
Sector
BR1 1
BR1 2
BR1 3
BR1 4
BR1 5
BR1 9
BR2 0
BR2 6
```

All the results from `FixedResults` are included within `TestResults` and the looped processing can end.

The syntax of the loop itself is straightforward

```
WHILE (*condition*)
BEGIN
    *process*
END
```

My question is how do I test that ALL the items in `FixedResults` are in `TestResults` in the context of a `WHILE` loop?

Comment: Sounds like you should rethink the whole strategy. You *rarely* need a loop in T-SQL, at the most you might need a recursive CTE. Please show sample data and expected results, as well as what actual code you have so far (inside the loop)

Comment: `SELECT .. FROM FixedResults EXCEPT SELECT ... FROM TestResults` will "subtract" the two tables. Per Charlie, though, it seems like what you really ought to be doing instead is rethink this whole logic to operate in a set-based manner, and not just this part alone. Even in cases where things are being done by an sproc, it more often than not pays off to open the black box and rewrite at least part of it to fit in "proper" queries. And where this is truly not possible, you tend to be better off shifting the driver logic to the client side, as that offers far more flexibility and performance.

Comment: I totally agree, I have avoided loops within SQL like the plague. Unfortunately in this case I am cleaning up data and there is no obvious set based answer to account for the crazy things the user has been allowed to do over the years.

Comment: Like I said, if you show us what you are doing, we might be able to make it set-based. Either way we can't help without a [mcve], with things like sample data, expected results and a proper explanation of the logic.

Comment: If you choose to answer a different question than the one asked then that is your prerogative. However, the original question is totally fair and does contain data, an explanation and a clear indication of the required result.